# What use is QRegExp::pos() without a corresponding QRegExp::len() of sorts?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qregexp

In a project I'm working on, I need to make a [`QStringList`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstringlist.html) out of all [`QRegExp`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html) captures **except** for 2 of them: the 1st one and one of the other ones, depending on some other parameters.

The straightforward approach would be to use [`QRegExp::capturedTexts()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#capturedTexts) and then remove from the returned list the two unneeded items. This however implies that two `QStrings` and related `QList`'s nodes need to be allocated just to be trown away without any real use, which seems wasteful.

I then thought I would just build a `QStringList` myself one captured text at time, via `QRegExp::cap()`. But `QRegExp::cap()` is [itself implemented in terms of](https://github.com/nonrational/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6/blob/master/src/corelib/tools/qregexp.cpp#L4292) `QRegExp::capturedTexts()`, which would make my code look funny, at the very least.

So I looked at the API and found the pretty convenient [`QRegExp::pos()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#pos) method, which, the documentation states, «*Returns the position of the nth captured text in the searched string.»*

Pretty neat, I thought, I could then use [`QString::mid()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html#mid) and build the `QStringList` myself. This is [what the actual implementation](https://github.com/nonrational/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6/blob/master/src/corelib/tools/qregexp.cpp#L4259) of `QRegExp::capturedTexts()` [does](https://github.com/nonrational/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6/blob/master/src/corelib/tools/qregexp.cpp#L4259), after all.

Except I wouldn't know how to retrieve the nth captured text **length**, which I need to extract the captured text by means of `QString::mid()`. Indeed, the position and the length of any of the captured texts are stored one beside the other, as [can be seen](https://github.com/nonrational/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6/blob/master/src/corelib/tools/qregexp.cpp#L4322) in the `QRegExp::pos()` [implementation](https://github.com/nonrational/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.6/blob/master/src/corelib/tools/qregexp.cpp#L4322), but there's no accessor for the length info, unless I'm terribly mistaken, a case for which I apologize in advance. :)

So, here's my question: if I'm correct and there's no way to retrieve any given captured text's length, what use case does `QRegExp::pos()` have? I can't imagine any situation in which I'd want to know just where the captured text begins, without being able to retrieve it.

__

PS. Qt5 [`QRegularExpressionMatch`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpressionmatch.html) class provides the methods [`capturedStart()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpressionmatch.html#capturedStart) and [`capturedEnd()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qregularexpressionmatch.html#capturedEnd) that fill this void, but I'm stuck with Qt4.8.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an API bug. That's all. I wish there was some magic trick to it - there isn't, as far as I know. I wouldn't worry too much about allocating the `capturedTexts` return value unless this is a parser that is invoked on lots and lots of text. Use what you've got - probably any time you spend on tweaking this is time wasted at this point unless you're pushing millions of lines of text through this thing.

Comment: That's what I'm going to do, of course, but I was curious about what uses could `QRegExp::pos()` have that I can't imagine.